# How do I know where my Archaeology dig sites are?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I'm probably missing something obvious, but without having to open up my world map and click through every zoomed-in zone map, is there any way to narrow down where dig sites will be? For clarification, I'm talking about the big, red, general "survey around here" splotches.

- Are they always in the same places?
- Do they spawn in every possible location, or is it like other gathering professions where there are a list of possibilities and a sub-list of current "active" places?
- Are there dig sites in all zones, or at least a majority of them?
- Can I always trust clicking through the zones to find the next dig site I should visit, or are there some that don't appear until I'm closer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a finite list of Archaeology digsites. Your 4 active digsites per continent will always be drawn from that list. A comprehensive listing of them can be found [here.](http://www.wowdigs.com/locations.htm) Not all zones have digsites, but most do.

You should be able to see your active digsites while looking at the continent map. They'll be marked with a small shovel icon: [image: Shovels!]

While the shovels are not perfectly precise, they're close enough, and once you get nearby, you can look at the zone map to see the exact boundaries of a dig site in question.

Comment: Ah, nice complete answer, thanks. For others' reference, the shovels can be very hard to see on the non-maximized world map.

Comment: -1 for non-freehand circles.

Comment: @echo: to be pedantic, you can't see shovels on the world map, only continent maps.

Comment: @nick: But since you will *always* have 4 digsites per continent on every continent (for which you have sufficient skill, 300 required for Outland, 375 for Northrend), that point is *slightly* moot.

Comment: Is it--can you see the shovels on the standard Blizzard map?  I use a map mod so it might be hiding them.